# How to use python-wheel code in python shell?

Tags: python-3.x, libraries, python-wheel

I try to learn how to create a Python library. But I have a problem with activating a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/). To be more specific: I was told to do this:

[code from Realpython: virtual environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clUsg.png)
.. I opened my console:

[![image|510x490](upload://zqb3BdSuq5XipqvbPHZMJND0r3r.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOc1X.png)

and paste the mentioned code:

```
$ python -m venv env && source ./env/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install -U pip wheel setuptools
Successfully installed pip 20.1 setuptools-46.1.3 wheel-0.34.2
```

But It was rejected (and I couldn't find on the internet why is that - probably the solution is simple, but I don't even know how to post a proper question to find it):

[![image|690x359](upload://oKNbP6ohfVekQpN4wa5NoyKZkrd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqorm.png)

I tried to pate this code without dollar sing but it won't work too, also replacing `$` with `!` won't work.

[![image|644x255](upload://rrod0WdZiO64nQAblPebOittice.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nra4P.png)

I don't know why it doesn't work and what version of this code should I use.

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use windows :) go to linux. `$` is special linux terminal symbol. The `source` is linux command too. [guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/). Use windows commands if you use windows. But the better way is going to linux.